# Obter item de linha com exceção de uma coluna

Tags: jquery, html, table

Olá!

Eu gostaria de uma ajuda referente ao clique em uma tabela.

Quando eu clicasse na linha viesse os dados desta linha, exceto quando clicado em uma coluna específica (coluna 3 por exemplo), porque eu quero fazer outra ação na coluna em questão.

Trazer os dados da tabela eu já consigo, falta somente pôr em exceção a coluna que eu gostaria.

Agradeço...

```js
$("tr").on('click',function() {
   var tableData = $(this).children("td").map(function(){
                    return $(this).text();
                }).get(); 
                var codigo =  $.trim(tableData[0]) ;
                alert('Codigo: '+codigo);
                
 })
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.js"></script>

<table class="table table-responsive table-hover">
  <thead>
    <th>ID</th>
    <th>Nome</th>
    <th>Status</th>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>Carlos</td>
      <td>Ativo</td>
    </tr> 
    <tr>
       <td>2</td>
       <td>Charles</td>
       <td>Inativo</td>
    </tr> 
    <tr>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>Ozeias</td>
      <td>Ativo</td>
    </tr> 
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Essa coluna de excepção tem alguma classe em particular?

Comment: tem não. Pelo menos ainda

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podes dar uma classe a essa coluna e excluí-la com

```
 if (e.target.classList.contains('excluir')) return;
```

Exemplo:

```js
$("tr").on('click', function(e) {
  if (e.target.classList.contains('excluir')) return;
  var tableData = $(this).find("td").map(function() {
    return $(this).text();
  }).get();
  var codigo = $.trim(tableData[0]);
  console.log('Codigo: ' + codigo);
})
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.js"></script>

<table class="table table-responsive table-hover">
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>Carlos</td>
    <td class="excluir">Ativo</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>Charles</td>
    <td class="excluir">Inativo</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>Ozeias</td>
    <td class="excluir">Ativo</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: fiz uma edição lá. Adicionei um `thead> th`. Continua o mesmo conceito?

Comment: @adventistaam é igual, `th` neste caso não muda nada na resposta.

Answer (score 0):

Você pode adicionar uma classe nessa linha específica. Por exemplo vamos colocar uma class **c1**.

O código ficaria assim.

HTML :

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.js"></script>

<table class="table table-responsive table-hover">
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>Carlos</td>
    <td>Ativo</td>
  </tr> 
  <tr>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>Charles</td>
    <td>Inativo</td>
  </tr> 
  <tr class="c1">
    <td>3</td>
    <td>Ozeias</td>
    <td>Ativo</td>
  </tr> 
</table>
```

JavaScript:

```js
 $("tr").on('click',function() {
   var className = $(this).attr('class');
   
   if(className == "c1"){
      alert("Ação diferenciada para esta linha");
      return;
   }

   var tableData = $(this).children("td").map(function(){
                    return $(this).text();
                }).get(); 
                var codigo =  $.trim(tableData[0]) ;
                alert('Codigo: '+codigo);
                
 })
```

Assim quando se clicar em uma linha da tabela será verificado se esta possui a class **c1**, caso sim executará aquela ação diferenciada. Coloquei apenas um alert pois não sei o que você pretende fazer.